# Bonferroni correction for pairwise proportion comparisons for more than one outcome level

Tags: confidence-interval, multiple-comparisons, proportion, bonferroni

Suppose I have an event that can have 3 different outcomes. This event is recorded for 21 different factor levels for a total of 100 times, and each time an outcome happens it is counted (so I am dealing with proportions)

Let's say my dataset looks like this:

```
   Factor Total Outcome1 Outcome2 Outcome3
1       A   100       43       10       47
2       B   100       43       11       46
3       C   100       56       19       25
4       D   100       72       10       18
5       E   100       75       11       14
6       F   100       65       18       17
7       G   100       68       10       22
8       H   100       78       19        3
9       I   100       40       18       42
10      J   100       75       14       11
11      K   100       79       13        8
```

Suppose I am interested in doing pairwise comparisons between each of the factor levels and level A, separately for each outcome (i.e. 10 pairwise comparisons within each outcome type, for a total of 30 pairwise comparisons)

In other words, I am interested in looking at (and quantifying) the difference in the proportions between level A and the other levels, for each of the three possible outcomes.

I am able to calculate the confidence interval of each of their differences using `prop.test()` in `R`. However, the confidence intervals are likely overly narrow and p-values are inflated due to the multiple tests.

My question is: if I were to use Bonferroni correction for this, I would change my alpha to be:

$\alpha_{new} = \alpha/n = 0.05/n$

However I am not sure if $n$ should refer to the total number of level comparisons within each outcome (i.e. 10) or if it should refer to the total number of comparisons in total for all possible outcomes (i.e. 30)

How would I apply the correction in this case? After adjusting the confidence interval, would I also have to adjust the p-value that comes with the prop.test() results? (assuming I set `conf.level=(1-adjusted_alpha)` in its arguments)

Comment: $n$ refers to the number of comparisons you actually make. If you have five levels of a factor, the total number of pairs you _might_ look at is ${5 \choose 2} = 10,$ so for a 'family' error level of 5% you would need error level 0.5% for each comparison if you look at all 10. But if you're really interested in just comparing Level 1 (control) against each of four treatments, then you'd be dealing with only $n = 4.$ // The Bonferroni method is 'conservative'; that is, it may be too reluctant to declare differences. You might see if another method is applicable in your situation.

Comment: @BruceET Thanks - so if I am making comparisons looking at level 1 against each of the four treatments under three different outcomes, would $n$ be $4\times 3=12$ in this case? Since I am making 12 comparisons. (Assuming I'm using Bonferroni)

Comment: Here is my view. If others strongly disagree, I suppose we will see their Comments. If I understand your design correctly, I'd tend to view the 3 outcomes as being different 'families' and use $n = 4.$ These seem to be natural comparisons you would have planned to make from the start, not _ad hoc_ comparisons you're desperately dredging up after looking at the data. This, along with the inherent conservatism of Bonferroni, minimizes the danger of 'false discoveries'. Even so, I wouldn't make strong claims in a publication for comparisons that are just barely significant.

Comment: For future reference: It's good practice to write a prospectus at the start of a study like this, clearly stating the main objectives, perhaps stressing the objectives for which you've made power computations to plan needed sample size. Then when it comes to multiple comparisons, you know your decisions how to analyze them are truly not prompted by last-minute rationalizations. // I think it 'd be best for science if journals 'accepted' rsch plans and promised to publish results even if not all that was hoped for. We're not there yet. Maybe crises like recent one in psych will get us closer.